# Align the text in enumerate (or itemize) with the item number

Tags: enumerate, itemize

How can we align the text in enumerate (or itemize) with the item number?
Also, how to add a parenthesis after the item number and make the two in bold and italic?

An example of what I am looking for:

***1) AAAA:*** bbbb
cccc
***2) DDDD:*** eeee
ffff

Comment: Have a look into the `enumitem` package manual, but personally, I don't like this alignment -- it does **not** improve readability

Comment: I think that in my case it does, since some items contain more than 10 lines with lots of formulas (so I need more space per line..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `itemindent` from `enumitem` you could do something along the lines of this...

Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\sample}[1]{\textit{\textbf{#1:}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[itemindent=.5cm,label={\textbf{\textit{\arabic*}})}]
\item \sample{AAAA} bbbb\\cccc
\item \sample{DDDD} eeee\\ffff
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `enumitem`, you have to use:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\emph\bfseries\arabic*),wide=0pt]
\item ...
\end {enumerate}
```

for a single enumerate, or, for each enumerate (1st level),

```
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\emph\bfseries\arabic*)},wide=0pt}
```

in your preamble.